# Executing a query in VB6

Tags: sql, ms-access, vb6

I'm trying to execute a query in VB6. At the moment I have this:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset


Private Sub Form_Load()
 Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
 conn.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = " & App.Path & "\DB1.mdb; Persist Security Info = False"
 conn.Open
End Sub

Private Sub Command1_Click()
 Dim strSQL As String
 strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = " & Text2.Text
 rs.Open strSQL, conn
End Sub
```

This results in a `object variable or with block variable not set`.

I'm kind of new to VB and Access databases, so any answers or links to good tutorials would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rs` is never instantiated. Try

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
```

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```

before running rs.Open.
Same idea as the connection, the object needs to be instantiated first.
Other than that you're ok.

It's also good practice to close the rs and connection when you're done with them.

Comment: +1 This should be the answer.  Using `Dim X As New Y` has side effects that you need to understand, so its use should generally be discouraged.  It certainly shouldn't be posted as a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

You don't instantiate the `rs` in your coding

```
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
```

Also check your query
that is use the `name` in `where` condition as below if the name is text type

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = '" & Text2.Text & "'
```